# How to solve `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.ansible'` while running ansible using Gitlab?

Tags: ansible, gitlab

**Aim**

The aim is to deploy software once the build passed using Ansible and Gitlab.

**Problem**

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -u root --private-key=key.pem
```

deploys the software, but

```
sudo -u gitlab-runner ansible-playbook playbook.yml -u root --private-key=key.pem
```

results in:

```
PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.ansible'
fatal: [system.example.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "stdout": ""}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
system.example.com        : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

**Discussion**

1. Running `ansible-playbook --help` shows that `-u` is the
   remote_user. As this is set to `root` the issue should not occur.
2. logging in as `gitlab-runner` and subsequently run `ansible-playbook playbook.yml -u root --private-key=key.pem` succeeds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause**

Issue was caused because the host was omitted from the known host file that resides in the home directory of the `gitlab-runner` user

**Solution**

1. login as `gitlab-runner`, i.e. `sudo su - gitlab-runner`
2. run playbook, i.e. `ansible-playbook playbook.yml -u root --private-key=key.pem`
3. enter `yes` if `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?` appears
4. click the `retry` button in gitlab to restart the build